# How to built a multiple window application with full screen feature?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have a WPF (C# with .NET 4.0) application which displays 'panel' / windows. No problem so far with `Grid` and different rows/columns for each panel.

Now I would like to expand one panel to full screen (like Eclipse does for each view when double clicking). Is there a built-in solution in WPF or do I have to implement this behavior by myself?

Are there open source solutions for this feature? I could not find any.

Comment: The search terms you're looking for are 'multiple document interface' or 'mdi'

Comment: I do something similar. Nothing high-tech I'm afraid - each panel has an maximise/restore button whose event handler changes the grid's row heights and column widths to make that particular panel fill the available space and shrink the other panels down to nothing. It first stores the current widths & heights, allowing me to restore the panel sizes when the button is clicked a second time.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I thought about the same strategy, which seems feasible to implement without too much effort. I just wondered, if there was something built-in since this task seems common for me for nowadays applications. But unfortunately there is nothing built-in in WPF... :-(